# How to decrease the time sqlalchemy used to connect to database and select data

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm a beginner to data science and my recent job is to select data from company's database with some conditions using python. I tried to achieve this by using sqlalchemy and engine, but it takes too long to get all the rows I need. I can't see what I can do to reduce the time it performs.
For example, I use following codes to get total orders of a store during a time period by its store_id in the database:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, select, Table, func, and_, or_, cast, Float
import pymysql

#create engine and connect it to the database
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:*******@127.0.0.1:3306/db')
order = Table('order', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)


#use the store_id to get all the data in two months from the table
def order_df_func(store_id):     
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    stmt = select([order.columns.gmt_create, order.columns.delete_status, order.columns.payment_time])
    stmt = stmt.where(
        and_(order.columns.store_id == store_id,
             order.columns.gmt_create <= datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
             order.columns.gmt_create >= get_day_zero(last_month_start.date()) #func defined to get 00:00 for a day
                )
        )
    results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.columns = results[0].keys()
    return df

#get the data in a specific time period
def time_bounded_order_df(store_id, date_required_type, time_period):
    order_df = order_df_func(store_id)
    get_date(date_required_type)# func defined to get the start time and end time, e.g. this week or this month
    if time_period == 't':
        order_df = order_df[(order_df['gmt_create'].astype(str) >= start_time) & (order_df['gmt_create'].astype(str) <= end_time)]
    elif time_period == 'l':
        order_df = order_df[(order_df['gmt_create'].astype(str) >= last_period_start_time) & (order_df['gmt_create'].astype(str) <= last_period_end_time)]
    return order_df

#get the number or orders
def num_of_orders(df):
    return len(df.index)
```

It takes around 8s to get 0.4 millions results, which is too long. Is there anyway I can adjust my code to make it shorter?

Update

I tried to select data directly in the mysql workbench and it takes around 0.02s to get 1000 results. I believe that the question comes from the following code

```
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

But I don't know anyway else I can store the data to a pd.dataframe. Any thoughts with that?

Update2

I just learned that there is something called 'indexes' in the table that can decrease the processing time. My database is given by the company and I can't edit it. I'm not sure if it's the problem of the table in the database or I still need to do something to fix my code. Is there a way I can 'use' the indexes in my code? Or it should be given? Or can I create indexes through python?

Update3

I figured out that my database stopped using indexes when I select several columns, which significantly increased the processing time. I believe this is a mysql question rather than a python question. I'm still searching on how to fix this since I barely know sql.

Update4

I degrade my mysql server version from 8.0 to 5.7 and indexes in my table started to work. But it still takes a long time for python to process. I'll keep trying to figure out what I can do on this.

Comment: I tried to directly select the time period I need in the database and return len(results) instead of select two months' data and store them in the pd.dataframe. It will increase the times I need to visit the database, and only low down the time by one second. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Have you read this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html

Comment: @SuperShoot Thank you for this document! I'll see if I can use that to locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I used

```
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.columns = results[0].keys()
```

then you're resaving all the data from database to python, and since I didn't create indexes for python, the resaving time and searching time is very long. However, in my case I don't need to resave the data in python, I just need the total count of several variables. So, instead of select several columns, I just use

```
stmt = select([func.count(yc_order.columns.id)])
#where something something
results = connection.execute(stmt).scalar()
return results
```

And it runs just as fast as it inside mysql, and question is solved

P.S. I also need some variables that count total orders in each hour. I decided to create a new table in my database and use schedule module to run the script every hour and insert the data in the new table.